# Validar contraseña con Array

Tags: java, array, contraseña

Estoy realizando una tarea y necesito comparar dos arrays (completos) para hacer un ejemplo de validación de contraseña.
En el primer array tengo la contraseña:
`char clave[]={'j','a','m','o','n'};`
Y el segundo array lo pido por teclado, este sería la contraseña introducida por el usuario:
Primero lo declaro con `char pin[]=new char [clave.length];`
Y después lo recorro así:

```
for (int j=0; j<clave.length; j++){
            System.out.println("Introduzca su clave");
            pin[j]=teclado.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Hasta el momento todo bien, pero no sé como comprobar que el array **clave**(declarado) y el array **pin**(introducido) sean el mismo.  Este es todo mi codigo hasta ahora:

```
public class compararContras {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        char clave[]={'j','a','m','o','n'};
        char pin[]=new char [clave.length];
        System.out.println("Introduzca su clave");
        
        for (int j=0; j<clave.length; j++){
            System.out.println("Introduzca su clave");
            pin[j]=teclado.next().charAt(0);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<clave.length;i++) {
            if (pin[j] == clave[]) {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Las cadenas y los caracteres se deben comparar con:

```
textoA.compareTo(textoB)
```

Si es != 0, significa que no son iguales, por lo que en tu caso, si todas las letras del array clave son las mismas que las del array que introduce el usuario, la contraseña es válida.

**¿Cómo haces eso?**

Lo más sencillo es ir recorriendo los dos *array's* y comprobar si todas las letras en la posición *i* son iguales, si en algún punto no son iguales paras el bucle y devuelves un *false (lo paras con un break)*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, entiendo la solución, pero no controlo mucho el tema Java aún y no sé cómo implementarlo en mi código ¿Podrías ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Ya he conseguido lo que buscaba, creo:

```
public class compararContras {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        char clave[]={'j','a','m','o','n'};
        char pin[]=new char [clave.length];
        System.out.println("Introduzca su clave");
        
        for (int j=0; j<clave.length; j++){
            System.out.println("Introduzca su digito nº");
            pin[j]=teclado.next().charAt(0);
        }
        if (Arrays.equals(clave, pin))
            System.out.println("La clave es correcta");
        else
            System.out.println("La clave es erronea");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).